# Mapping and sql database creation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5, localdb

I started a project and use Entity Framework 5.
Now I created a database on my SQL Server Express with all tables.
Further I created the `DbContext` with a fluent mapping.

What is better, the fluent mappings or the `.edmx` mapping files?

The database is now on the SQL Server but I want support also SQL local db.

Is there a way to tell the `EF` that I want to use a SQL local db?

Should I ship the whole database within the setup or better to create the database on startup of my application? How can I use `EF` to create the database (SQL server or SQL local db)?

Every useful help would be appreciated.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716372/is-localdb-supported-by-visual-studio-2010-in-entity-framework-5

Comment: @spajce: Thanks so far for this.

Comment: can't you simply tell which database to use via your app.config / web.config?

Comment: and I wouldn't see why you want to ship the database, if EF creates it for you at application startup in a blink of an eye. maybe it helps to google on some nice EF documentation?

Comment: Yes. How can I create the database programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF5 I would stay away from edmx.
You could reverse engineer your model from database using Entity Framework Power Tools.
Than you can customize your model using either Data Annotations or fluent mappings.

If you use EF5 code first it can create database automatically for you if not present, however that would not work very well on subsequent upgrades (it can recreate database but then you will use or your existing data). The options you could use, is either EF migrations, where you can specify in fluent-like languagage the modifications that were made to your database or use Database Project in Visual Studio, where you can store all your schema in source control and then generate database upgrade scripts betweeen releases.

Comment: Why should I stay away from edmx? What is if I update the database and reverse engineer my model again, are than all my changes overridden?

Comment: Well, that was my impression after reading this article http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/code-first-and-dbcontext-are-now-ldquo-the-entity-framework-rdquo/ seemed like edmx is now second class citizen. However, the other good comparison is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148150.aspx where they suggest that if you prefer visual designer and have existing database then database-first may be the way to go.